# In Driver: San Francisco which cars can reach 170MPH?

Tags: driver-san-francisco

In Driver: San Francisco I'm trying to do the Speed Dare "Accelerate 0-170MPH - no abilities".

So far I haven't found a car that will do 170MPH, which cars can go this fast?

Comment: I've found one car that will do 170MPH, so answered my own question. Hopefully someone can come up with a more complete answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Audi TT RS will do 170MPH, this can be bought in the garage for 20,000.